# Using C++ SQL to Add Relationship to Microsoft Access Table

Tags: c++, sql, ms-access, ado, dao

I'm trying to add a CONSTRAINT/RELATIONSHIP between two Microsoft Access Tables using C++ (MFC-based) (through ODBC) with the following SQL Command:

```
ALTER TABLE [JobSettingsReporting] 
           ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PerEntry 
           FOREIGN KEY (JobSetID) 
           REFERENCES JobSettingsEntry(JobSetID) 
           ON UPDATE CASCADE 
           ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I tried to do it with this:

```
CDatabase db;
db.OpenEx(App().GetDBConnectString());
db.ExecuteSQL(strSQL);
db.Close();
```

where strSQL is the Query above. I'm getting the error:

```
Syntax error in CONSTRAINT clause.
```

It seems the problem is with the "ON UPDATE CASCADE" and "ON DELETE CASCADE" components. I get the same error when I use the Query Design tool (or in VB) within Microsoft Access.

However, when I do the following in VB in Microsoft Access, it works:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection 'For action queries
Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
cn.Execute "ALTER TABLE [JobSettingsReporting] 
                ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PerEntry 
                    FOREIGN KEY (JobSetID) 
                    REFERENCES JobSettingsEntry(JobSetID)
                ON UPDATE CASCADE 
                ON DELETE CASCADE"
```

This command also seems to work in SQL Server Express when directly using the Query Window.

It is my understanding that I need to use Jet/ADO to issue this command in C++ for it to work but I'm having trouble finding the syntax.  I need to add this relationship programmatically so that it will update the databases on all the deployed machines.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you use OleDb instead ODBC to connect to the Access db?

Comment: Where can I find an example of OleDb calls?  My attempts at implement the query using OleDb have not been successful.

Comment: In other programming contexts such as VBScript, you could open an ADO connection wich uses the ACE or Jet provider: [Access connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/).  I have no idea how to do that in C++.